# How to write “egg baby” with the same innuendo or word play as 터래기 meaning fur baby?

Tags: translation, phrase-meaning, wordplay

This is an unconventional request but a Korean artist created a brand called  Teolaegi 터래기 which from my very basic understanding is a play on words for fur baby. How would one do the same for ‘egg baby’? Is it only straightforward as 계란베이비 or 아기알? Or is there wordplay available?

Egg Baby is to be cute and endearing

Comment: Sorry this is not an answer, but I don't think 터래기 is particularly cute - it's just an OK made-up word. If I heard that word out of context, I might have thought it was made of 털+(쓰)레기 (fur + garbage).

Answer (score 0):

터래기 is just 털아기 spelled after its everyday pronunciation (아기 is often pronounced as 애기 in the central region of South Korea).  It doesn't sound like any commonly heard word though.

For "egg baby", 알아기/아래기 would be a similar construction to 털아기/터래기.  아기알 is more like "baby egg" (like "small egg"). But I'm not sure if people actually use such a word.